# Find the sum of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi(2k+1)((\pi(2k+1))^2-4L^2)}$, $L\in(0,1)$

Tags: analysis

Find the sum of the series
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi(2k+1)((\pi(2k+1))^2-4L^2)}, L\in (0,1)$ ?

Is it possible to find the sum?

I know $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{((\pi(2k+1))^2-4L^2)}= tan (L)/8L$.

I am trying to split $\dfrac{1}{\pi(2k+1)((\pi(2k+1))^2-4L^2)}$ in to  two peaces and tried to apply above identity.

But I am not able to split it !

Is there any way to ans this or atleast Is it possible to make some bound for $\dfrac{1}{\pi(2k+1)}$ inside the sum?

Answer (score 1):

*I do not know if this is the answer you could expect.*

Using partial fraction decomposition
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi  (2 k+1) \left(\pi ^2 (2 k+1)^2-4 L^2\right)}$$ $$a_n=\frac{1}{8 L^2 (\pi  (2 k+1)-2 L)}+\frac{1}{8 L^2 (\pi  (2 k+1)+2 L)}-\frac{1}{4 \pi
    (2 k+1) L^2}=b_n+c_n-d_n$$ Now, using generalized harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{k=0}^p b_n=\frac{H_{-\frac{L}{\pi }+p+\frac{1}{2}}-H_{-\frac{L}{\pi }-\frac{1}{2}}}{16 \pi 
   L^2}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^p c_n=\frac{H_{\frac{L}{\pi }+p+\frac{1}{2}}-H_{\frac{L}{\pi }-\frac{1}{2}}}{16 \pi  L^2}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^p d_n=\frac{H_{p+\frac{1}{2}}+2\log (2)}{8 \pi  L^2}$$ leading to
$$\sum_{k=0}^p a_n=-\frac{-H_{-\frac{L}{\pi }+p+\frac{1}{2}}-H_{\frac{L}{\pi
   }+p+\frac{1}{2}}+H_{-\frac{L}{\pi }-\frac{1}{2}}+H_{\frac{L}{\pi }-\frac{1}{2}}+2
   H_{p+\frac{1}{2}}+4\log (2)}{16 \pi  L^2}$$

Using the asymptotics, we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^p a_n=-\frac{H_{-\frac{L}{\pi }-\frac{1}{2}}+H_{\frac{L}{\pi }-\frac{1}{2}}+4\log (2)}{16
   \pi  L^2}-\frac{1}{16 \pi ^3 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ and then the limit you are looking for.

Comment: I thought $\pi(2k + 1)$ was an action of the prime counting function, haha